# How to find the QLineF exceeds parent bounding rect

Tags: qt, qpainter

Im having a line drawn from the calculated value of the source. The points P1 and P2 are set from the value I'm getting from the other source and using these points I'm drawing the line. In some cases the line is going out of the `boundingRect` of the parent item.

The line is visible outside the parent rect, so I have to restrict the line length to certain or to be inside the bounding rect of the parent item.

Is there an easy or best way I could check such a condition?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about a `QGraphicsItem` you can [set the parent flag](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#setFlags) to `QGraphicsItem::ItemClipsChildrenToShape` so its children can't draw outside of it

Comment: No Actually i have to get the notification and restrict it outside and second thing i cant control the parent flag . it is global to other items including mine .